# how to get validation errors through ajax in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to use ajax within my submit form in a codeigniter. I have it to where the ajax call is made, bu the validation errors are not displaying. I can't figure out why. Please help.

I do have some returns in there, but they do nothing.

```
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
   {
   echo(json_encode("validate"=>FALSE));
   }
   else
   {
  $this->load->model('adduser_model');
  $data['query']=$this->adduser_model->adduser();
   }
}
```

view code:

```
<script>
    //CHECKS ONE FIELD AT A TIME
    $(function(){
        $(".field").each(function(){
            $(this).keyup(function(){
            var id = $(this).attr("id"); //VALUE OF INPUT ID Ex: <input id="name">
            var v = $(this).val(); //INPUT TEXT VALUE
            var data = id+"="+v; //DATA TO GO TO THE AJAX FILE Ex:(name=wcet)

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "prog/validate", //AJAX FILE
                data: data+"&single=true",
                success: function(e){ //"e" IS THE DATA FROM "validate.php"
                    $("span#"+id).html(e); //ECHOS DATA FROM "validate.php" NEXT TO THE     INPUT IF NEEDED
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
</script>

 <BODY>
<?php $this->load->helper('form');
echo form_open('prog/validate'); ?>
<tr><td align="right">Name: </td><td align="left"><input class="field" name="name"      id="name"> <span id="name"></span><br></td></tr>
<tr><td align="right">email: </td><td align="left"><input class="field" name="email" id="email"> <span id="email"></span><br></td></tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you `have some returns` that means the function was successful. Even if you didn't have the response you expected, the `$this->form_validation->run()` will be false ONLY if the `$ajax` call couldn't fire at all (404, 500 errors).

You can also trying catching the error via `failure: function () {}`, for example:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "prog/validate", //AJAX FILE
    data: data+"&single=true",
    success: function(e){ //"e" IS THE DATA FROM "validate.php"
        $("span#"+id).html(e); 
    },
    failure: function(e) {
        // check against error messages
    }
});
```